# Pip3 is pointing to wrong python version

Tags: python-3.x, pip

My pip3 is pointing to python3.7 (i don't have python 3.7 in my bash_profile..?) but my python3 points at python 3.6.3.

Before i've used the command: python3.6 -m pip install X,

but after updating to macOS Catalina the command gives me the following error:

$ python3 -m pip install pandas
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3: No module named pip.**main**; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: How can i solve this? plzzzzzz help